# Url rewrite one step further

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am using this rule now and it is applied to my members...

RewriteRule ^member/([0-9]+)/([^.]+).html$ member.php?id=$1&name=$2

And it is looking like this:

http://www.mysite.com/member/1/Foo_Smith.html

I want to take this further and deeper into the site like this:

http://www.mysite.com/member/1/Foo_Smith/Gallery.html
http://www.mysite.com/member/1/Foo_Smith/Gallery/viewPhoto/nice_picture_i_took.hmtl

Pages in my root is galleri.php and viewPhoto.php

Any ideas if this is possible and any examples on how to achive this?

Best regards, Joakim

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^member/([0-9]+)/([^./]+)\.html$ member.php?id=$1&name=$2
RewriteRule ^member/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/Gallery\.html$ gallery.php?id=$1&name=$2
RewriteRule ^member/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/Gallery/viewPhoto/([^/]+)\.html viewPhoto.php?id=$1&name=$2&photo=$3
```

I haven't tested it, but I think it should work.

Comment: OK, the third needs a ID to the viewPhoto.php to fetch it from the database? Do I just add a new variable or does it have to be like http://www.mysite.com/member/1/Foo_Smith/Gallery/viewPhoto/99/nice_picture_i_took.hmtl

Comment: `RewriteRule ^member/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/Gallery/viewPhoto/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)\.html viewPhoto.php?id=$1&name=$2&photoid=$3&photo=$4`

Comment: Almost there, the first id needs to be switched to the other photoid...I cant manage to clue that one out?